# How to add dojo event to a new elements on a form?

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

I have a form, so every form has its own delete link, I add questions dynamically with JS, I have following dojo function to make delete link works...

```
dojo.ready(function() {
   dojo.query(".delete-link").onclick(function(el){
      if(confirm("Really delete?")){
       ......
      }

   });
 });
```

That function works properly, but when I add more questions (using JS), that new questions don't have the event on the delete link, any Idea to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the click event was bound to all links that have the class "delete-link" on page load. When you create a new element through JS, it does not get automatically bound to that function because that link was not present on page load. You need to bind the link at the document level so that when the link is added, it will be automatically bound.

Bind it this way instead:

```
on(document, ".delete-link:click", function(){})
```

This is equivalent to jQuery's .live() function.

Please note that you'll have to require dojo's on module (dojo/on)